# Submit image from Userform to a table column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Userform to submit records for our equipment into a table.

It populates a new row in a table. One of the columns of the table is a picture of the equipment.

I added code to open a picture and upload it to the Userform as an image using the Image Control (I tested and this works so far).

I would like to add the picture to the correct column when I click Submit and clear the image control afterward. I have the image control to size the picture at 60 pixels by 110 pixels in order that they will all be the same size.

Below are the code and pictures I have so far:

```
Dim fpath As String
Private Sub Label6_Click()

    Dim x As Integer
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    x = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    If x <> 0 Then
        fpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
        Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(fpath)
        Picture1.PictureSizeMode = 1
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the File path to the image in a global variable outside the sub.  On your submit function, select the cell it goes into then `<Sheet>.Pictures.Insert(<PathToFile>)`.  To clear the picture `Picture1.Picture = Nothing`